# First letter to be capitalize Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this code :

```js
$("input").keyup(function() {
  var data = this.value.split(" ");
  $('p').append(data.slice(0));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="search">
<p></p>
```

I want the first letter of this array to be capitalize, thanks for your help !

Comment: `$('p').text($(this).val().split(" ").map(str => str && str[0].toUpperCase() + (str.length > 1 ? str.slice(1).toLowerCase() : '')).join(" "));`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

`data[0] = data[0].toUpperCase();`

Answer (score 1):

Use Javascript Prototype..

```js
String.prototype.capitalize = function() {
  return this.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.slice(1);
}


var test = "hello";

console.log(test.capitalize())
```